# Match string like ?$skip=[0-9]

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match oData string like so `^\$skip=[0-9]$` to match things like `$skip=3` and remove them. My regex is probably wrong but I don't know what to try next. I've already tried various things like wrapping it in `[]` and so on.

Here is an online example: http://www.regexr.com/392m2

Comment: what's your language?

Comment: @Fede my language is c#. It doesn't work still :|

Comment: You're example includes a question mark at the start of the line, but your regex doesn't account for that. With the question mark removed, your regex works fine.

Comment: [This pattern](http://www.regexr.com/392m5) will match `$skip=3` part. But really, that's the basics.

Comment: @Steve can you paste a sample of the data you want to parse? It'll help to give you a more accurate answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `^\$skip=[0-9]$`. This regex will match only a line that has that pattern. The line must start and finish with `$skip=N` so, that's why your test didn't work.

If you have $skip=3 separated from your words you can use:

```
\b\$skip=\d+\b
```

Above will match only if you have: `blabla blab bla $skip=3 bla`

If you only want to remove it's appearing you can use `\$skip=\d+`

```
\$skip=\d+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hoGF5rQh6kbApxqW)

Above will match if you have: `blabla blab bla$skip=3bla`

Comment: Yea I needed `\$skip=\d+` because if I had `$skip=299` my approach didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match `skip=3` then try the below regex,

```
(?<=\$).*$
```

A positive lookbehind is used to match all the characters which are next to the literal `$` symbol.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iX5iR4)

OR

you could use `\K`, to discard previuosly matched characters.

```
\$\K.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wT9gL5)

OR

```
^\?\$\Kskip=[0-9]$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wD2tK1)